# Best way to post element [data] to server side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using asp.net - C#, i have a form in my web page with a few elements.
Depending on what the user does, i change the data of elements using jQuery like this:

```
$("#elemntID").data('someKey','someValue');
```

When i post the form i know how to get the value and even the text of the element and im using it.
But, i need to get also the .data on the server side.
I though of a few ways:

1. Create a Json array of all the elements that hava data and their data and then create an hidden field that his text or value will be a serialized array that i later convert back to array on server side.
2. Use some sort of ajax to post simultaneously with the form.

Now i'm asking you.. how will i do it ?

Comment: Use ajax calls to create server side POST events and there you can post your data easily.

Comment: _ajax to post simultaneously with the form_ This is not a good idea. Use only ajax to post all the data to the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var DATA = {key1 : 'value1', key2 : 'value2' };
```

and

```
$.ajax({
        url: "address/to/your/apiOrServie",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(DATA),
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer `jQuery AJAX` function, `$.ajax()`, [jQuery/ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**Example**

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "SERVER_URL",
  data: {
    name: "John",
    location: "Boston"
  }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
});
```

Hope it helps!